# GraphQL post request in axios

Tags: reactjs, graphql, axios

I have a problem with GraphQL. I want to send axios.post request to my server. I can do it in postman:

```
{
    "query":"mutation{updateUserCity(userID: 2, city:\"test\"){id name age city knowledge{language frameworks}}} "
}
```

and in graphiql:

```
mutation {
  updateUserCity(userID: 2, city: "test") {
    id
    name
    age
    city
    knowledge {
      language
      frameworks
    }
  }
}
```

but can't do it in my code:(( here is my code snippet:

```
const data = await axios.post(API_URL, {
  query: mutation updateUserCity(${ id }: Int!, ${ city }: String!) {
    updateUserCity(userID: ${ id }, city: ${ city }){
      id
      name
      age
      city
      knowledge{
        language
        frameworks
      }
    }
  }
}, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
```

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Probably good reference, looks like the query string does not have data in it. 
 https://medium.com/@stubailo/how-to-call-a-graphql-server-with-axios-337a94ad6cf9

Comment: no, I tried that method, but it didn't help

Comment: https://graphql.org/graphql-js/passing-arguments/

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Value of `query` parameter to be passed in request has to be string and names of variables passed to GraphQL queries should be prefixed by `$`. You have used string literals for variables in request instead. Also, variables can be passed in post request using `variables` key.

Changing your code to something like below should get it to working:

```
const data = await axios.post(API_URL, {
  query: `mutation updateUserCity($id: Int!, $city: String!) {
    updateUserCity(userID: $id, city: $city){
      id
      name
      age
      city
      knowledge{
        language
        frameworks
      }
    }
  }`,
  variables: {
    id: 2,
    city: 'Test'
  }
}, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
```

Comment: I had to wrap the curly braces in variables in backticks to make it work

Comment: What if arguments is of custom type? then how to do it?

Comment: @DevAKS: I did not understand what you meant by custom type. Can you please share example?

Comment: @Raeesaa you are accepting argument in your mutation as Int and String variable, so instead let's say you have user defined type for example - Location {lat:  Int,  lng: Int}

Comment: @DevAKS https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables  https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types

Comment: `axios.post()` has three args if `headers` are needed, otherwise 2.

Answer (score 12):

I enjoy using the following syntax, which is similar to the accepted answer, but more explicit.

Note that the `variables` object is nested inside of the `data` object, and is a sibling of the `query` object.

```js
const data = await axios({
  url: API_URL,
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    // ...other headers
  },
  data: {
    query: `
      mutation updateUserCity($id: Int!, $city: String!) {
        updateUserCity(userID: $id, city: $city) {
          id
          name
          age
          city
          knowledge {
            language
            frameworks
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      id: 2,
      city: 'Test'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there `JSON.stringify()` needed for `data`?

Comment: @Timo there is no need to `JSON.stringify()` the `data` with axios. For reference: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Answer (score 2):

i would like to share you my simple working example

```
            let id = "5c9beed4a34c1303f3371a39";
            let body =  { 
                query: `
                    query {
                        game(id:"${id}") {
                            _id
                            title
                        }
                    }
                `, 
                variables: {}
            }
            let options = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
            axios.post('http://localhost:3938/api/v1/graphql',body, options)
                .then((response)=>{
                    console.log(response);
                });
```

Comment: This is not how it's supposed to be done. GraphQL has a dedicated variable interface and this can easily break when input contains quotes.

Comment: This worked for me, with a few modifications. Thank you!

Comment: using string literals for variables is abusing graphql, far less safe/readable/manageable

Answer (score 1):

for WordPress GQL
https://docs.wpgraphql.com/getting-started/posts/
This seem to work for me at this moment with Nuxt

```
async asyncData() {
const data = {
  query: `query GET_POSTS($first: Int) {
    posts(first: $first) {
      edges {
        node {
          postId
          title
          excerpt
          date
          content
          author {
            node {
              username
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`,
  variables: {
    first: 5
  }
}

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  data: data,
  url: 'http://localhost/graphql'
};
    
try {
  const response = await axios(options);

  console.log(response.data.data.posts.edges);
  console.log(response.data.data.posts.edges.length);
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to pass variables into the query. Unless I'm wrong, what you have in the axios call and the others are different.

```
const data = await axios.post(API_URL, {
  query: `
    updateUserCity(userID: ${id}, city:${city}){
      id
      name
      age
      city
      knowledge{
        language
        frameworks
      }
    }
  `
}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

I believe this should work, assuming you have the variables `id` and `city` defined before this call.

Comment: This is not how it's supposed to be done. GraphQL has a dedicated variable interface and this can easily break when input contains quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data like this:

```js
const email = "test@gmail.com";
const password = "123";

const data = await axios.post(
  API_URL.Loging,
  {
    query: `query{
      login(
        email:"${email}", 
        password:"${password}"
      )
      {
        userId
        token
      }
    }`,
  }
);
```