# Implementing NoSql GraphQL Queries on React frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql

I would like to ask how to implement on react frontend the graphql that I have created on the server side.

Here is my server side query, it does work on playground and I'm able to pull individual transactions based on the memberId but I'm not sure how to implement it on the front end. [image]

Here is my front end Query

[image]

Here are the rest of my codes for the Frontend using react

```
import {getTransactionQuery} from "../queries/queries.js"


 const UpdateTransaction = props => {


   let data = props.getTransactionQuery.getTransaction ? 
props.getTransactionQuery.getTransaction : [];

        return (
        <Container>
            <Columns>
                <Columns.Column >
                    <Card>
                        <Card.Header>
                            <Card.Header.Title><p>Availed Transactions</p> 
          </Card.Header.Title>
                        </Card.Header>
                        <Card.Content>
                        <Table striped bordered hover>
                                  <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>Date Selected </th>
                                      <th> Amount Availed </th>
                                      <th> Edit Amount </th>
                                      <th> Confirm and Pay </th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                    {data.map(transaction => {
                                        console.log(transaction);
                                        return (
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                <Moment format="LL">
                                                 {transaction.bookDate}
                                                 </Moment>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>{transaction.availedNumber}</td>
                                                <td> 
                                                <Button> Approve </Button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                  </tbody>
                                </Table>
                            </Card.Content>
                        </Card>
                    </Columns.Column>
                </Columns>
        </Container>
    )
  }


 export default compose(


  graphql(getTransactionQuery, { name: "getTransactionQuery" }))

   (UpdateTransaction);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood, you don't know how to send your query to your backend?

Comment: yep, I am able to query All the transactions if I do pull all the documents using map, but what i need to get is the specific transaction that has the memberId that created that transaction.

Comment: okay, so follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868182/7827130 ;)

Comment: is the backend working correctly and your problem is sending the graphQL request?

Comment: as per the first image, using graphql playground, the backend query is working fine, I just don't know how to display the query on the frontend