# "message":"Request failed with status code 500","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 500\n

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, http-post

**I wanted to fetch data from open API from this [link](https://digitransit.fi/en/developers/apis/1-routing-api/). According to the documentation, The HTTP method must be POST and Content-Type must be either "application/graphql" or "application/json". I used node express server to fetch the data. But when run the server I got error. From this API I wanted to display on browser public transportation timetables between one location to another location.**

**Ps. I never fetched Graphql open api.**

```
   const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const axios = require("axios");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(morgan("common"));
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const url = "https://api.digitransit.fi/routing/v1/routers/hsl/index/graphql";
app.get("/hsl/timetables", async (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/graphql"
      }
    })
    .then(response => res.send(response.data))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("catch error", err), res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: You've set the method to `POST`, but you're still calling `axios.get`, and your request has no actual body.

Comment: Did you check the link, Which I shared? I used axios.post method  and add body but I still get same error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "message":"Request failed with status code 500","name":"Error","stack":"Error: Request failed with status code 500

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868182/6124657  (`data` contains `query` and `variables`) ... you can test axios from client (f.e. react)  ... https://api.digitransit.fi/graphiql/hsl - check headers in dev tools/network  - compare headers with your react axios requests ... then use in node

Answer (score 0):

If you notice in the Axios docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) you do not need to have the method in your options . (Remove this `method: "POST",`).

Also, you will want to change the request to a `.post(` instead of a `.get(` like you have

You will need to include a body in your request as well.  This will be where you need to figure out what you want.  I'm not sure what routes you are looking to display but as an example,

```
let data = {
  routes(name: "10") {
    gtfsId
    shortName
    longName
    mode
  }
}
```

You can find lots of examples on what you data should be for whatever query you want

To add it all up, you would have something like this:

```
axios.post(url, data, {
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/graphql"
    }
})
```

Comment: Nope. Did not help @MindlessRouse. Still the same issue.

Comment: i structured the data like this:
`let data = {
  plan(from, to, transportModes) {
    itineraries: {
      legs: {
        startTime, endTime, mode, duration, realTime, distance, transitLeg;
      }
    }
  }
};`