# How to properly send a GraphQL update request using Axios?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, graphql-js, aws-amplify

I created an application using AWS Amplify, and I want to create an endpoint in an API function that will mutate a field in GraphQL. Since its a nodejs API function, I cannot use the recommended libraries from the [AWS documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/graphql-from-nodejs/q/platform/js/#create-from-scratch) which use ES6, since the functions can only use ES5. Therefore I need to use Axios.

I created a graphql query:

```
const query = /* GraphQL */ `mutation updatePublication($id: ID!, $keywords: String) {
                    updatePublication(id: $id, keywords: $keywords){
                      id
                      keywords
                    }
                  }`
```

Next, I created the Axios request based on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816623/graphql-post-request-in-axios).

```
const data = await axios.post(
        process.env.API_APPNAME_GRAPHQLAPIENDPOINTOUTPUT,
        {
          query: query,
          variables: {
              id: variableWithID,
              keywords: "updated keywords!"
          }
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-api-key': process.env.API_APPNAME_GRAPHQLAPIKEYOUTPUT
          }
        }
    )
```

When I run the query, I get a status 200 from the server with the following errors:

```
  data: null,
  errors: [
    {
      path: null,
      locations: [Array],
      message: "Validation error of type MissingFieldArgument: Missing field argument input @ 'updatePublication'"
    },
    {
      path: null,
      locations: [Array],
      message: "Validation error of type UnknownArgument: Unknown field argument id @ 'updatePublication'"
    },
    {
      path: null,
      locations: [Array],
      message: "Validation error of type UnknownArgument: Unknown field argument keywords @ 'updatePublication'"
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anyone advise on what this means?

Comment: _"the functions can only use ES5"_... what do you mean by this?

Comment: For nodejs, I cannot use "import blah", and can only use "require". Not all packages like axios support ES5 and ES6.